# How to read customised hdfs file with hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs, protocol-buffers

I have my own file format in HDFS, like below

`<bytes_for_size_of_header><header_as_protobuf_bytes><bytes_for_size_of_a_record><record_as_protobuf_bytes>...`

As we can see, each record inside the file is encoded with protocol buffer

I've been trying reading these files with hive, and I supposed that I should create an inputformat, a record reader from the older version of mapreduce API, and also a serde to decode the protobuf record.

Does anyone ever done this before, am I going in the right direction? Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are going in the right direction.  This is exactly what the `InputFormat`, `RecordReader`, and `SerDe` abstracts are for.  You should be able to find plenty of examples.

Comment: Thanks!@climbage, actually I have already created un inputformat and recordreader but with the new version of mapreduce API, and they are not compatible with hive since hive use the older mapreduce API, do you think there is a way to transform them to be able to be used in hive?

Comment: I don't... I have always just back-ported them.  There may be a new, better way to do it now though.